# Symfony 4 not loading associated entity

Tags: symfony, associations, entity

Here are the two classes:

`User`:

```
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Teams", inversedBy="id")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
    */
    private $team;
```

`Teams`:

```
class Teams
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="team")
     */
    private $id;
```

I'm trying to retreive team informations from my view with: `dump(app.user.team)` but give me a not loaded entity...

```
Teams {#450 ▼
  +__isInitialized__: false
  -id: 3
  -name: null
  -password: null
   …2
}
```

Where am I wrong ? I don't know what is wrong...

regards !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nothing wrong. As you can see in your dump, the id of teams's entity is loaded.
You can access all attributes of this object.
try `dump(app.user.team.name)`, you have access to it.

All attributes are not loaded due to lazy loading